# It hurts my "feeling" vs "feelings"

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions, nouns

One can see both variants used. Are both correct? And what the difference, if so?

I suppose, when word "feeling" is used in this this context, the phrase must be extended with the mention of concrete feeling the speaker refers to.

Comment: Actually Ngrm shows no usage of *it hurts my feeling*: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+hurts+my+feeling%2Cit+hurts+my+feelings&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20hurts%20my%20feelings%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh61 That's as what i thought. I think the phrase `it hurts my feelings` is pretty idiomatic. And derivative `it hurts my feeling of ..` (e.g. `beauty`, `the beautiful`) is not the same "unit of language", one may say.

Comment: Yes *feelings* has a more idiomatic  and restricted usage: ***Feelings*** (plural) 1) emotional or moral sensitivity, as in relation to principles or personal dignity (esp in the phrase hurt or injure the feelings of)
2) ***have feelings for***  to be emotionally or sexually attracted to. (Collins)

Comment: The idiomatic version of "it hurts my feeling of fairness|justice|aesthetics|(whatever)" is "it offends my sense of ..{X}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, to summarize the comments:

1. It is not correct to say `it hurts my feeling`
2. There is no such idiom as `it hurts my feeling of ..`
3. The idiomatic version of `it hurts my feeling of fairness|justice|aesthetics|(whatever)` is `it offends my sense of ..{X}`

Thank you to all commenters.

Comment: Excellent job of putting together your own answer! :-)